# Get total of balance in Paypal account in .net

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

How can I get the (total) balance of my PayPal account?
I want to display like "My PayPal Account balance"

I want to do it in .Net.

Comment: Find paypal webservice that will send you this info. I just found one                     http://sourceforge.net/projects/paypal/

Comment: Thanks, but i want it in .net

Answer (score 0):

Use [PayPal's GetBalance API](https://www.x.com/paypal-apis-getbalance-php-5.3/nvp) . You have the option of calling the SOAP API or via the Name Value Pair option